# Carto Builder, show attribute readout synced to time data in animated map?

Tags: carto, time, animation

I'm working on a donated webmap animating time data, the progress of small electric boat across the ocean. The time field for animation is a time in seconds counter from launch attribute. The data table also has fields for proper date (text as mo,day,year) and boat telemetry for solar voltage, pitch, and roll.

Is it possible to have readouts in the map for these other attributes, updated by the specific time point in the animated data?

Comment: If you want to display categorical or numeric data on your Torque map, there is already answered [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/208222/animating-quantitative-values-in-carto-torque-cat).

Comment: No, that' not it this time. Carto Builder actually allows the 2nd variation value directly now (e.g. color animation by category while animating by time). What I want is a readout for other fields in the data table, but synced to the animation running on the time field. So a separate set of labels for Date, Voltage, Pitch, and Roll that all sho their values for the time period at each frame of the animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible to do it with BUILDER. You need to code a HTML/JavaScript application with [carto.js](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/carto-js) to fetch your data and sync it with the torque animation. You have a full tutorial [here](https://github.com/CartoDB/carto-workshop/blob/master/06-sdks/exercises/cartojs.md) and an example similar on what you want to do [here](http://bl.ocks.org/ernesmb/4939b3751d3be0cdd64b).

Comment: So not at all possible to call a dynamic label via the CSS editor then? Not enough time to do a custom site, but thanks for the links.