# Why isn't CartoCSS picking my conditional values a carto animated layer?

Tags: carto, cartocss, css, torque

I am making an animated layer and the values I want to map range are from 0-1, as a percentage (e.g. `0.33333`). I'm trying to change the color and eventually size based on the value.

I tried adding conditional statement based on this example, but it looks like it is only picking up the first value. Maybe I don't understand the order the conditional statements are being evaluated.
I'm adapting code from this example:
[Animating quantitative values in Carto Torque Cat?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/208222/animating-quantitative-values-in-carto-torque-cat)

```
Map {
  -torque-frame-count: 233;
  -torque-animation-duration: 30;
  -torque-time-attribute: "date";
  -torque-aggregation-function: "CDB_Math_Mode(value)";
  -torque-resolution: 4;
  -torque-data-aggregation: linear;
}
#layer[frame-offset=1] {
  marker-width: 8;
  marker-fill-opacity: 0.5;
}
#layer[frame-offset=2] {
  marker-width: 10;
  marker-fill-opacity: 0.25;
}
#layer [ value <= 1] {
  marker-fill: #21b100;
}
#layer [ value <= 0.8] {
  marker-fill: #E31A1C;
}
#layer [ value <= 0.6] {
   marker-fill: #FC4E2A;
}
#layer [ value <= 0.4] {
  marker-fill: #FD8D3C;
}
#layer [ value <= 0.2] {
  marker-fill: #FEB24C;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Animating quantitative values in Carto Torque Cat?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/208222/animating-quantitative-values-in-carto-torque-cat)

Comment: Thanks @ramiroaznar, that does help but my map still doesn't quite work as expected. I updated my question and description. Any other ideas of what's wrong?

Comment: Can you share the link to the dataset?

Comment: Sure, here's the link to my map. https://weatherpattern.carto.com/dataset/module07_171009_bikeshare

Answer (score 1):

In order to create an animated map styling the points based on a field, you need to follow these steps:

1. Go the layer `STYLE` tab and select `Animated` from the aggregation methods.
2. Select `date` as COLUMN.
3. Switch the slider from VALUES to CartoCSS (now the hacky part begins).
4. Replace `count(cartodb_id)` with something like `avg(avail_ratio*100)`. Click o APPLY.
5. Remove the last two blocks of code if you do not want to have the halo/trace effect (optional).
6. Add CartoCSS conditional blocks, but within the `layer` block. You will end up with something [similar to this code](https://gist.github.com/ramiroaznar/2524aecbe7404f9b9cef478b737da8cd).

And the result should be like this:

[image: torque-by-value]

Comment: Thanks Ramiro. I was able to further refine my results into categories and it looks like it is working now.